# delete foreign key laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

I have these tables : **posts, users, tags, categories**
I know that when we delete a **user**, then we should delete **posts** that belong to that special user. I do it within my migration:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

so I don't know if I remove a post, should I remove **tags** that belong to that **post** or same story for categories....
If I remove a post, what about **post_id** field in tags table?
or categories??

Comment: yes, you should delete post_tag relationship and category_post relationship, but it's not exactly delete a tag or delete a category, it's just delete the record of relationship.

Comment: @HanlinWang so we should do this in every relationship that has foreign keys ???

Comment: that's the case if you want delete record, usually we never delete data, we use soft delete to mark a record as delete, laravel support that. using soft delete can keep the data, sometimes it may become valuable in future.

Comment: thank you dear @HanlinWang :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, assuming post tag is many to many, and post category is many to many too, you should delete post_tag relationship and category_post relationship, but it's not exactly delete a tag or delete a category, it's just delete the record of relationship.

so you can add `->onDelete('cascade')` on `post_tag` table and `category_post` tab if you are using default name convention.